# In-App Billing inventory prices not always the same currency that will be shown when the user intents to buy

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

My Android app is utilizing In-App-Purchases / In-App-Billing and the process in whole is working nicely so far. The only problem that I have is that sometimes the currency changes in the process. What I mean is, the price / currency that I get when I query the inventory by utilizing `mHelper.queryInventoryAsync()` is sometimes different than the one that will be presented when the user clicks on the item to buy.

For example, there was a user from Greece, for a reason the queryInventory method returned the price in pounds and it was only after the user clicked on the product to buy, google presented him the price in euro. The user later told me, that he got his Nexus 7 from the UK but his credit card is from greece. So this might explain it, but still it confused him, and seeing as it already happaned to one of my test users, I can imagine this can happen more often.

Also I am not sure if its okay legally speaking if an app changes the currency in the process, the user might not know that google is at fault here.

So what I am asking here is, is there a simple way to force google to present the final price when I query the inventory? Or is there a simple way to find out in what currency the user will pay (maybe get the country from his sim card) and query googles inventory with the country variable?

Thank you in advance.

Here is my code:

```
    // googles IabHelper class
    private IabHelper mHelper;
    // this carries my products, gets filled in my activity by a request to my server
    private List<String> additionalSkuList = new ArrayList<String>();

    mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(true, additionalSkuList,
                        mGotInventoryListener);

    // Listener that's called when we finish querying the items and subscriptions we own
    IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener mGotInventoryListener = new IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener() {
        public void onQueryInventoryFinished(IabResult result, Inventory inventory) {
            L.debug("Query inventory finished.");

            // Have we been disposed of in the meantime? If so, quit.
            if (mHelper == null) return;

            // Is it a failure?
            if (result.isFailure()) {
                L.debug("Failed to query inventory: " + result);
                return;
            }

            Set<String> skuKeys = inventory.getSkuKeys();

            List<String> exceptList=new ArrayList<String>();
            mHelper.flagEndAsync();

            for (final String sku: skuKeys) {

            // this price is not always the one which will be shown when someone
            // would start the IAB process                  
            String price = inventory.getSkuDetails(sku).getPrice();                 

      }
    };
```

Comment: Did you read this article? https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/1169947?hl=en&ref_topic=15867

Comment: yes, did you read my question? it does not help me with the different currencies.

Answer (score 1):

If I am in Greece and I use an American card linked to my bank account that has US dollars in it, Google will first the price in Euros.

When they find out I am paying in dollars by checking my card it will change to dollars.

There is no way to know what currency a user will pay with before they pay unless you add a currency choice in your app and query the exchange rate yourself, or you go through the users private payment information (don't do that even if you can).

EDIT: However, you may be able to decide the currency based on the system language chosen or some other identifying factor.

Comment: thank you for your answer, so i guess it is like that "by design" and there is nothing broken with my implementation

Comment: Yea, I wouldn't worry too much about it. It seems like something that might not happen too often, and even so, its a time consuming but easy fix for a small inconvenience. People shop online in foreign countries and do price conversion themselves all the time.